# parse ics and create output

Tags: bash, awk, icalendar

This is an ics file containing three test events. Using bash, I want to create a table containing just the DTSTART and SUMMARY.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:emailaddress@gmail.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Nicosia
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T050000Z
DTEND:20221016T053000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:494jpt5pm5lhfn47mv1eppp0hm@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143242Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143242Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 8am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T040000Z
DTEND:20221016T043000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:55j049svjglavmlqu8evdfbe8n@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143233Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143233Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 7am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T030000Z
DTEND:20221016T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:054od4tq8eisl2s6eoa33rsdbc@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143220Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143220Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 6am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

So the output should be

```
16/10/2022 08:00 test event 8am
16/10/2022 07:00 test event 7am
16/10/2022 06:00 test event 6am
```

One thing I noticed is that even though the events were scehduled for 6am, 7am and 8am, the time in the ics is shown as UTC+0. But I'm located at UTC+3, so the DTSTART values are 3 hours back. No idea why.

Comment: `bash` and `awk` are two different languages; which do you want to use? (You should *not* use `bash`; running `awk` *from* `bash` is not the same as *using* `bash`.)

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code; how are we to determine the 3hr offset? do you enter that manually or do you rely on your system's timezone setting?

Comment: yes, I mean any languages available in bash, like awk, perl, grep, cat, sed or whatever I can use in a shell script.

Comment: no, I don't enter a 3hr offset manually. I just enter events in google calendar and then export the ics file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:emailaddress@gmail.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Nicosia
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T050000Z
DTEND:20221016T053000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:494jpt5pm5lhfn47mv1eppp0hm@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143242Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143242Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 8am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T040000Z
DTEND:20221016T043000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:55j049svjglavmlqu8evdfbe8n@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143233Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143233Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 7am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T030000Z
DTEND:20221016T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:054od4tq8eisl2s6eoa33rsdbc@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143220Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143220Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 6am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}/^DTSTART/{dtstart=$2}/^SUMMARY/{summary=$2}/^END:VEVENT/{print substr(dtstart,7,2)"/"substr(dtstart,5,2)"/"substr(dtstart,1,4),sprintf("%02d",substr(dtstart,10,2)+3)":"substr(dtstart,12,2),summary}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
16/10/2022 08:00 test event 8am
16/10/2022 07:00 test event 7am
16/10/2022 06:00 test event 6am
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is colon (`:`). For lines starting with `DTSTART` I set dtstart variable value to content of 2nd field, for lines starting with `SUMMARY` I set summary variable value to content of 2nd field. For lines starting with `END:VEVENT` I do print earlier collected data, I do process datetime mainly using [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to get desired elements and cocantenate them, in case of hour I do add 3 as stipulated by requirements and then need to format it with leading zero (to get fixed width) for which I do harness `sprintf` function.

**Disclaimer**: I assume time offest is etched in stone AND it is acceptable to have hours outside 0...23 range, e.g. you might get say `16/10/2022 25:30` due to mentioned plus three, feel free to improve that if it is not acceptable, however keep in mind that this might lead to situation which lead to increase in day which requires change in month which requires alteration of year (e.g. `31/12/2021 25:30`)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: on Sunday the clocks go back 1 hour. I'm assuming that +3 will have to become +2, right?

Comment: this is not working if an event is marked as recurring. any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk

```bash
gawk -F: '
    @include "join"
    function timestamp(ts,    m, t, epoch) {
        if (match(ts, /([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})Z/, m)) {
            t = join(m, 1, 6, " ")
            epoch = mktime(t, 1)
            return strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", epoch, 0)
        }
        else
            return ts
    }
    /BEGIN:VEVENT/,/END:VEVENT/ {
        if ($1 == "DTSTART") printf "%s ", timestamp($2)
        if ($1 == "SUMMARY") print $2
    }
' file.ics
```

which, for me in UTC-04:00 time zone, outputs

```
16/10/2022 01:00 test event 8am
16/10/2022 00:00 test event 7am
15/10/2022 23:00 test event 6am
```

For a timezone that's UTC+3

```bash
TZ=Africa/Djibouti gawk -F: '...' file.ics
```

we see

```
16/10/2022 08:00 test event 8am
16/10/2022 07:00 test event 7am
16/10/2022 06:00 test event 6am
```

Ref: [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) in the gawk manual.